# How do I print all records in file 1 but note the records that do not match file2?

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

Is there an easy way to print all lines of a `file1` (so that the output has the same number of lines as the input `file1`) but print a message such as `NoMatch` where the first entries of file1 does not match the first entries of `file2`?

file1:

```
Entry1 Entry2
a 2
b 3
c 4
d 5
```

file2:

```
a
b
b
a
d
d
```

Desired output:

```
Entry1
a 2
b 3
NoMatch 4
d 5
```

I am trying with

```
join -a1 -e "NoMatch" -11 -21 -o2.1 file1 file2
```

since I would like to keep the unpairable lines from `file1` that do not match `file2`, and give a message for these cases as "no", but this keeps all of my records also in `file2` (which contains duplicated records), what am I doing wrong? Could this be because my second file is tab delimited and my first file is space delimited?

Thanks so much for all the help...

Comment: Yes that is right... I have other columns that belong to file 1 though that identify the unmatched, let me make that clearer...

Comment: Hmmm. Looks similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247223/139893.  I wonder why?  In that question, there was also a problem with a tab-delimited file.

Comment: It is the same question made up of two, I will correct the other one sorry.

Comment: Why use two different logins?

Comment: You seem to have created two accounts. Please visit the [contact form](http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. That way you'll be ab;e to respond to comments and properly manage all your posts.

Comment: it was a mistake, I hadn't registered the first question and when I tried to reply I registered. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` read `file2` first and save `$1` in `seen[$1]` then read `file1` and if `$1` wasn't "seen" replace it with `NoMatch`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]++; next}
{(FNR==1 || ($1 in seen)) || $1="NoMatch"};1' file2 file1
```

If you prefer `join`, you need sorted input. You'll have to extract the `head`er from `file1` first, `sort` the remaining lines then `join` the result with the `sort`ed `file2`:

```
{ head -n1; sort | join -j1 -a1 -e "NoMatch" -o 2.1 1.2 - <(sort file2); } <file1
```

and if needed, pipe everything to `uniq` to avoid duplicate lines:

```
{ head -n 1; sort | \
join -j1 -a1 -e "NoMatch" -o 2.1 1.2 - <(sort file2) | \
uniq; } <file1
```

Comment: Thanks so much don_crissti! Can I ask why I can't just ignore the header since it won't match to the other file anyway? I think I have been doing this wrong all along :/

Comment: Thank you... I still can't get it to print my second value for the output, it prints "NoMatch" for the whole row...I don't understand why...

Comment: I think I am using the brackets incorrectly, I get a syntax error... sorry I am a beginner... if I try this one step at a time and get the sortedFile1 without header and sortedFile2 without header in tab delimited format and then try this: { join -t $'\t'  -a1 -e "NoMatch" -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.2,2.1  sortedFile2; } sortedFile1 )

Comment: then it prints the whole line as "NoMatch" if it doesn't find it... there is no hope I will understand why tonight I guess, I will use the awk though at this point, thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: I see what my issue is... I can get what I need from your awk command using paste with my file2... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247223/merge-and-print-matching-and-non-matching-values-between-a-smaller-file-and-a-hu